# configure tor to use only US proxies

Tags: unity, tor

Can anybody tell how I can configure my tor to use only US proxies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vidalia, open <kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Advanced</kbd>
and add this to your `torrc` file:

```
ExcludeNodes {be},{pl},{ca},{za},{vn},{uz},{ua},{tw},{tr},{th}, {sk},{sg},{se},{sd},{sa},{ru},{ro},{pt},{ph},{pa}, {nz},{np},{no},{my},{mx},{md},{lv},{lu},{kr},{jp}, {it},{ir},{il},{ie},{id},{hr},{hk},{gr},{gi},{gb}, {fi},{es},{ee},{dk},{cz},{cy},{cr},{co},{cn},{cl}, {ci},{ch},{by},{br},{bg},{au},{at},{ar},{aq},{ao}, {ae},{nl},{de},{fr}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your torrc file:

```
ExitNodes {US}
StrictNodes 1
```